# Motor For powered adult swing

Tags: design, motors, machine-design

I'm trying to design a powered swing for adults (similar to a baby swing, but scaled up). Am I right in assuming that this is functionally a pendulum and the power required is (0.5)mgsin(t)? How should I go about finding an appropriate motor?
I'm sorry if this sounds basic, but this is the first project I've ever done from scratch, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a fast estimate we assume the following:

- the only friction you swing experiences is air friction and l=2m, g=10ms^2.
- that $ \ \omega =\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}=\sqrt5=2.24rad.s^-1$
- we assume you set the swing to travel an angle of 2.24/2rad=1'12rad, so its frequency of 1 second. and it travels with an average speed of 2.24*2m=4.48m/s (not correct but reasonable)
- that the surface area of an adult sitting on the swing is 1 m^2

Now we calculate how much force we need to keep the swing moving against the air friction.

Drag force is $F=\frac{C_d*A*\rho*v^2}{2}$

- Assume C_d =0.75 for a sitting person
- Air density 1.225kgm^3

$$F=\frac{0.75*1*1.225*4.48^2}{2}=9.2N\ per\ second$$
$F*1.5_{safety factor}= 13.8watt.$

Just a rough estimate.

Comment: I'm just bugged by significant digits differences between g & air density.  It's me not you.

Comment: @TigerGuy, totally agree. old habits find a way to creep back on you!

Comment: Given that bearing friction has been ignored, then the error of taking g as 10 is already covered. And as for the detail of density, real engineers remember **so** many numbers - pi to 6 decimals, specific heat capacity of water (for me in SI units , others will remember in other units :) ), standard air pressure again of course in their usual units :), relative density values for common things like mecury - when doing lots of things with manometers one sees the numbers **so** often you just don’t have to look them up any more. Still love Geick Technical Formulae though.